# F# Interactive #I Generic Nuget Directory

Tags: f#, fsi

I have an F# script referencing a package in

```
%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages
```

FSI is happy with

```ml
#I @"C:\Users\Username\.nuget\packages"
```

but not

```ml
#I @"%USERPROFILE%\.nuget\packages"
```

How can the `#I` path be the nuget packages directory for the current user?

Comment: String.Join with one of these? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.specialfolder?view=netframework-4.8

Comment: No, #I paths have to be known at compile time.

Comment: In F# 5 I'll be able to skip all this with 
`#r "nuget: System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement"`